# How to define the selector to ignore the ones with children?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector like this:

```
$(source).find('.cb_notes').each(function() { .. } );
```

I would like to say ignore those `.cb_notes` that have any children.

e.g.:

```
<td class="cb_notes">huhuhu</td>
```

`$($('.cb_notes')[0]).children().length` --> 0 children, hence should be selected

and

```
<td class="cb_notes">
   <span class="shortcontent"> .. </span>
   <span class="allcontent"> .. </span>
   <span> .. </span>
</td>
```

`$($('.cb_notes')[1]).children().length` --> 3 children, hence should be ignored

Therefore how do I have to modify the slector here:

```
$(source).find('.cb_notes') ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions :

```
$('.cb_notes', source).filter(function(){return $(this).children().length==0})

$('.cb_notes:not(:has(*))', source)
```